# Snowflake query error - Divide by zero error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create this query (to use it as a KPI in the dashboard section) but I am getting the below error **Divide by zero**

The query that I am using:

```
with cte_ext as (

select count(*) as total_count

from snowflake.account_usage.query_history

where start_time = :daterange and

database_name = :database_name and

warehouse_name = :warehouse_name

), cte_conditional as (

select count(*) as "condition_count"

from snowflake.account_usage.query_history qh, cte_ext cte

where total_elapsed_time < 1000 and

start_time = :daterange and

database_name = :database_name and

warehouse_name = :warehouse_name

)

 

select round((cte_conditional.$1/cte_ext.total_count)*100,2) as "Percentage of queries run under 1s"

from cte_conditional, cte_ext
```

Could someone please, advice on how can I resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

---

Once I changed the query taking your advices, I was able to solve the issue and to get the null value.

Now I have the below question, is there any chance to replace the null value  to some text example like "No queries have been found or executed"?

Answer (score 0):

The value of cte_ext.total_count can be 0 in case no queries were executed for certain a start_time, database_name and warehouse_name. This would mean you are dividing by 0 in your later main SQL, which is forbidden.

To avoid this, you could wrap your code with a CASE-Statement:

```
Select Case when cte_ext.total_count=0 then null
Else round((cte_conditional.$1/cte_ext.total_count)*100,2) 
End as "Percentage of queries run under 1s"
from cte_conditional, cte_ext
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like for it to return zero instead, you may use `div0`

```
round(div0(cte_conditional.$1/cte_ext.total_count)*100,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports conditional COUNT so there is no need for multiple CTEs:

```
select 
  ROUND(100 * 
        DIV0(COUNT_IF(total_elapsed_time < 1000), COUNT(*))
       ,2) AS "Percentage of queries run under 1s"
from snowflake.account_usage.query_history
where start_time = :daterange
  and database_name = :database_name 
  and warehouse_name = :warehouse_name
```